# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied exception on tomcat

Tags: java, networking

my program is working fine on local desktop but when i have deployed it on domain and run the same program then it is showing following exception.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.abc.com:80 connect,resolve)

at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)

at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)

at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)

at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:233)

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:852)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:793)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:718)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:896)

at pnr.PnrServlet.processRequest(PnrServlet.java:46)

at pnr.PnrServlet.doGet(PnrServlet.java:81)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)

at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)

at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My program is to connect with other web site using java.net package 
and show relevant data
i am running this code on apache tomcat
please  help me.

Comment: Is this abc.com:80 correct machine? Does that exists?

Comment: i have replaced some other site name with abc.com in log only

Comment: The exception is pretty clear - `access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.abc.com:80 connect,resolve)`. You are trying to open socket 80 on a machine which you are not privileged on. You say you are deploying this app to Tomcat? Was it already running when you did so? Or are you trying to open a socket in your program directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat on your local machine is probably running without security turned on. On the actual server this is not the case and security manager is active. It is possible to grant the required `SocketPermission` privileges for your application for example by putting the following into the Tomcat security policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/your_app_root/-" {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "www.abc.com:80", "connect";
};
```

This should go into the policy file, which is normally under `conf/catalina.policy` but your installation may differ. You should replace the `file:` URI with the correct one for your case.

Please also read the detailed documentation on Tomcat security manager here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html.